# Horizontal Image Scroll with image resizing to fit height shows blank space

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have a horizontal image scroll view that resizes automatically based on the given content height. On top of each image, there's an overlay.

The issue I'm facing is that each `box` that contains the `image` and `overlayText` has a calculated width that is equal to the actual image resolution. This results in a lot of blank space right to the image.

The current CSS works on Chrome, and sometimes on Safari, but never on Firefox.

The example has a bit more elements than just the scroll view given there could be CSS instructions from parent divs that affect the scroll view.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhrrrr/18cymqtg/)

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rootReset {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-bg);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  width: 45rem;
}

.mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 30rem;
  overflow: none;
}

.viewContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftPanel {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 35%;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: none;
}

.rightPanel {
  flex: 1 1 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 2rem;
}

.viewContainer-content {
  margin: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box > * {
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
}

.box > :first-child {
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: none;
  display: block;
}

.overlayText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.lowerBlock {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='window'>
  <div class='rootReset'>
    <div>
      <div class='mainContainer'>
        <div class='viewContainer'>
          <div class='leftPanel'></div>
          <div class='rightPanel'>
            <div class='header'></div>
            <div class='viewContainer-content'>
              <div class='container'>
                <h2>TEST</h2>

                  <div class='box'>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://picsum.photos/2000/3000' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/1080/1920' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://picsum.photos/2000/3000' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/1080/1920' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class='lowerBlock'></div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#### EDIT

Here's a picture of how it's supposed to look like
[image: desired rendering]

#### Update 11/02/2020

The code above works if the `.box` div is setting a specific height.

The [simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhrrrr/4rt7pf6v/) that shows the flex layout is working when box has a value.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhrrrr/yrso7t4x/) is reproducing the layout bug in Firefox. The parent div is setting height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand what you would like to accomplish.
But should it act more like this?:

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rootReset {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-bg);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  width: 45rem;
}

.mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 30rem;
  overflow: none;
}

.viewContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftPanel {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 35%;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: none;
}

.rightPanel {
  flex: 1 1 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 2rem;
}

.viewContainer-content {
  margin: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.box > * {
  margin-left: 0.6rem;
}

.box > :first-child {
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.item {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.overlayText {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.lowerBlock {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='window'>
  <div class='rootReset'>
    <div>
      <div class='mainContainer'>
        <div class='viewContainer'>
          <div class='leftPanel'></div>
          <div class='rightPanel'>
            <div class='header'></div>
            <div class='viewContainer-content'>
              <div class='container'>
                <h2>TEST</h2>

                  <div class='box'>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://picsum.photos/2000/3000' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>Longer text!!</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/1080/1920' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://picsum.photos/2000/3000' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='item'>
                      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/1080/1920' />
                      <div class='overlayText'>img 4</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div class='lowerBlock'></div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Almost! I still want to retain image aspect ratio and scrolling. I added a screenshot of how my code is rendering Chrome; this is how I want it to look on all browsers.